# Как восстановить данные на виртуальной машине HyperV, если удалили все файлы кроме vhdx?

Tags: файловая-система, виртуальная-машина, восстановление, hyper-v, виртуальная-память

Сотрудник хотел почистить контрольные точки для виртуальной машины и сделал это через папку в которой они лежат, снёс всё, кроме образа жесткого диска, как итог машина не стартует, образ жёсткого диска почему то месячной давности.
Попробовал восстановить данные с помощью Recuva и Hetman Partition Recovery, нашёл .AVHDX файл с нужной датой, но ругается, что файл поврежден.
С горем пополам получилось сделать экспорт с данными хотя бы на месяц раньше.
Кто то знает есть ли шанс восстановить данные или всё потеряно?

Comment: образ диска той давности, когда была создана первая точка, в дальнейшем все изменения шли в инкременты типа avhdx, даже если вы их восстановите, то не уверен, что есть способ подключить их к VM